# Ubuntu setup boots to blank image

Tags: boot, 18.04

I tried install Elementary OS, Ubuntu live server, and Ubuntu 18.04 desktop. I had the same issue across all setups, they all boot to blank screens. I was able to "install" the server edition, only to boot to a blank screen too. I'm installing the OS from a partition on my hard drive that I made with LiLi USB Creator. I have tried both persistent mode and live mode only to no avail. I have uploaded a screenshot that you can check.

[image]

Edit: Was trying to install on Kingston SSDNow 300 120GB, apparently that didn't work. Installing on a 500GB Hard Drive worked, however. How can I install Ubuntu on the SSD?

Comment: Have you tried installing from a USB drive or CD instead? I'm just thinking that installing from the hard drive is non-standard and could lead to pitfalls, so using an external device might take some variables out of the equation.

Comment: To test what's the culprit, I tried install from USB then finally installing on a spare HDD I had lying around. It worked on my HDD. What could prevent Ubuntu from being installed on a SSD?

Comment: What SSD is that? Please [edit] the question if you want to add details.

Comment: Kingston SSDNow 300 120gb